# Having some 'two digit number' <= 'single digit number' jQuery issues

Tags: jquery

I'm using an `if` statement to display a hidden div. Users will push a button to cycle through the amount of hours they would like to book. The hours go up to 10 maximum. The `if` statement displays a notice if the `checkHours` is less than 5. Everything works perfectly fine until the user cycles to 10 hours. Apparently 10 is not less than 4, and the notice displays. If it's of any relevance, the `.hours-select` text is generated through an array of six options (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10).

Why is the `<=` not working for the number 10 in this case?

```
var checkHours = $('.hours-select').text();
var weekendNotice = $('.weekend-notice');

if(checkHours <= '4'){
    weekendNotice.fadeIn(500);
}else{
    weekendNotice.fadeOut(500);
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Because you're comparing strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'4'` and `'10'` are strings (collections of characters), not numbers. Strings are compared the same way as words in a dictionary - by comparing the first character, then the second character, etc. `'4'` is greater than `'1'`, so `'4'` is greater than `'10'`. To avoid this, don't put quotes around the numbers, and call `parseInt` on numbers taken from existing strings.

Answer (score 3):

try to use parseInt

```
var checkHours = parseInt($('.hours-select').text());
```

then

```
if(checkHours <= 4)
```

with out quotations